# how can i put sidebar menu in right side using yii2

Tags: yii2

iam developing a online application using yii2 . i want to use a side bar menu in my application. how can i create ? i have only navigation bar menu. i want sidebar menu in right side.`

```
  NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'Civil Department',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],

    ['label' => 'ApplicationsForms', 'url' => ['/site/index'],
 'items' => [

            ['label' => 'Casual Leave', 'url' => ['casual-leaves/create']],
            ['label' => 'Mtech Leave', 'url' => ['mtech-leave/create']],
            ['label' => 'Phd Leave', 'url' => ['phd-leave/create']],
            ['label' => 'Duty Leave', 'url' => ['duty-leave/create']],

        ],'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest // && Yii::$app->user->identity->level == Usertable::level1,

   ],
      ['label' => 'Leave Applications', 'url' => ['/site/index'],
 'items' => [

          ['label' => 'Applications for casual leave', 'url' => ['casual-leaves/index']],
          ['label' => 'Applications for Mtech leave', 'url' => ['mtech-leave/index']],
          ['label' => 'Applications for Phd leave', 'url' => ['phd-leave/index']],
          ['label' => 'Applications for Duty leave', 'url' => ['duty-leave/index']],

      ],'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest // && Yii::$app->user->identity->level == Usertable::level1,

 ],
          Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
            ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
            [
                'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
            ],
    ],
]);
NavBar::end();
?>
```

this is my navbar menu. what can i do for getting side bar menu. i want to re arrange the navbar. that is i try to put all the leave application in to sidebar .

composer.json

```
  "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
"description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",

},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
        "setPermission": [
            {
                "runtime": "0777",
                "web/assets": "0777",
                "yii": "0755"
            }
        ],
        "generateCookieValidationKey": [
            "config/web.php"
        ]
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

}

is this correct i only  add this line   "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "dev-master"
any other process for installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe simplest solution is use an extension like : http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/sidenav

For a fixed sidenav you can define a proper layout  or you can add you sidenav in you page ..  like this sample

```
use yii\helpers\Url;  // this is for Class URL ******
use kartik\widgets\SideNav;


        $menuItems[] =  ['label' => 'DFenX - Yii2 User - '. Yii::t('app','User Admin Panel'),  'icon' => 'cog', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/admin/index'])];
        $menuItems[] =  ['label' => Yii::t('app','Authentication manager'),  'icon' => 'th-list', 'items' =>  [    
                            ['label' => 'Settings', 'icon' => 'th-list', 'items' => [
                                ['label' => '/user/settings',  'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings'])],
                                ['label' => '/user/settings/profile', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings/profile'])],
                                ['label' => '/user/settings/account',  'url'=>Url::to(['user/settings/account'])],
                                ['label' => '/user/settings/networks', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings/networks'])],
                            ]],
                            ['label' => 'Registration', 'icon' => 'th-list', 'items' => [                                
                                ['label' => '/user/registration/register',  'url'=>Url::to(['/user/registration/register'])],
                                ['label' => '/user/registration/resend',  'url'=>Url::to(['/user/registration/resend'])],
                            ]],
                            ['label' => 'Security', 'icon' => 'th-list', 'items' => [                                
                                ['label' => '/user/security/login', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/security/login'])],
                                ['label' => '/user/security/logout',  'url'=>Url::to(['/user/security/logout'])],
                            ]],
                            ['label' => 'Recovery', 'icon' => 'th-list', 'items'  => [                               
                                ['label' => '/user/recovery/request',  'url'=>Url::to(['/user/recovery/request'])],
                                ['label' => '/user/recovery/reset',  'url'=>Url::to(['/user/recovery/reset'])],
                             ]],
                        ]];

        $type = SideNav::TYPE_PRIMARY;
        $heading = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> ' . Yii::t('app','USER Admin - UTILITIES');

        echo SideNav::widget([
            'type' => $type,
            'encodeLabels' => false,
            'heading' => $heading,
            'items' =>$menuItems,
        ]);
```

for installation see https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widgets or http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-widgets

Comment: i have an error Class 'kartik\widgets\SideNav' not found

Comment: Have you installed the extension ? .. see the link for info about this extension

Comment: how can i install the extension

Comment: i try this but have an other error  Class 'Url' not found

Comment: i add my composer.json file above

Comment: YOur composer is right. the "Class Url not found " is related to URL Helpers . ..use yii\helpers\Url;  I have update the answer with this ..

Comment: i tried but again the error become Class 'kartik\widgets\SideNav' not found

Comment: check for the correct installation  ... try installing all the widgets  "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*" and be sure you have execute composer in you project dir ..